# Cisco vpn AnyConnect freezes

Tags: kubuntu, vpn, cisco

Since yesterday (perhaps some system updates), the Cisco AnyConnect VPN makes the system freeze when I try to connect. It looks like a memory leak, since the memory used goes up to 90%. I am using Kubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

I removed the file `cert8.db` from the `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory and now it works again. I am not sure why this happened. The inspiration came from another problem I had long ago with the same client.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Thanks a lot!